# Downgrade the android version cause error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Developer, I am learning to develop xamarin.android application
I am just downgraded the my app android version from 7.0 to 4.3 to run the app on my mobile so it causes this error

also, refer some tutorials for beginners

[image: This is the actual screen shot of error]
[image: This is the full detail of error]

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: can you answer my question? I am very thankful to you

Comment: You need to improve your question if you want a chance of anyone answering it. You didn't add your code in a code block (and this site doesn't really like pictures). Asking for tutorials is off-topic. So no, there isn't enough info to even answer your question. That's why I gave you that link.

Comment: ok but which code should I add I am currently working on design s i have no idea about code that which code causes the error here so thats why i just post the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in an upcoming release. To resolve this, change your `Version` to a version that is > API 19.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56272

Otherwise upgrade to 15.3 in your Visual Studio Installer to receive this fix as it is included in Xamarin.Android 7.3.0.27 and above.